# How to use searchFile and searchFolder at the same time correctly? - App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The next script what it does is to search all the spreadsheets with a certain name in the drive starting from a certain folder.

```
function searchSSH(folder, path) { 
  if (folder == null && path == null) {
  return 
  searchSSH(DriveApp.getFolderById("ID"), "");
  }

  var files = [];

  path = path + "/" + folder.getName();  
  var searchFile = "fullText contains 'Project <>' and mimeType='" + MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS + "'";
  var fileIterate = folder.searchFiles(searchFile);

  while ( fileIterate.hasNext() ) {
    var file = fileIterate.next();
    var fileId = file.getId();
    var name = file.getName();
    files.push(name);

  for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
    Logger.log(files[i]);
  } 
 }

  var folderIterate = folder.getFolders();
  while(folderIterate.hasNext()) {
    var searchFold = searchSSH(folderIterate.next(), path);
    for (var i = 0; i < searchFold.length; i++) {
    files.push(searchFold[i]);
    }     
  }
  return files;    
 }
```

What I am trying to do is to see how I can do it so that I can also look for a certain folder just like the `searchFile` does and I try to do it like this...

```
    function searchSSH() {         
      var Folder =  DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");

      var folders = Folder.searchFolders('fullText contains "project"');
      while (folders.hasNext()) {
        var folder1 = folders.next();
        Logger.log(folder1.getName());
        for (var i = 0; i < folder1.length; i++) {
          files.push(folder1[i]);
        }     
      }

      var files = [];
      var searchFile = "fullText contains 'test <>' and mimeType='" + MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS + "'";
      var fileIterate = Folder.searchFiles(searchFile);

      while ( fileIterate.hasNext() ) {
        var file = fileIterate.next();
        var fileId = file.getId();
        var name = file.getName();
        files.push(name);

        for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
          Logger.log(files[i]);
        } 
      }       
      return files;    
    }
```

But doesn´t works. What I'm trying to do is to iterate through all the folders until I find the folder with the name `project` and keep iterating in that folder until I find all the spreadsheets with the `test` name but only search in the first folder.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. You want to retrieve the spreadsheet with the filename of ``test`` under the folder with the folder name of ``project``. Is my understanding correct? 2. What means ``only search in the first folder``? 3. Can I ask you about the detail of ``But doesn´t works.``?

Comment: I try to iterate between folders until I find the folder with the name `Project` and inside that folder keep iterating until I find the file with the name` Test` and that it is type spreadsheet, The first script if it finds the file but I want to specify I look inside the folders with the name `Project` to improve the performance of the script and the second script I'm trying is not iterating, that's why it does not work. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about your reply? Which part the answers to my questions are respectively? I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike Don't worry about that, i´m in the same problem that you about english skills jeje, let me enum my answers, 1. I try to iterate between folders until I find the folder with the name `Project` and inside that folder keep iterating until I find the file with the name `Test` and that it is type spreadsheet.

Comment: @Tanaike  2.The first script if it finds the file but I want to specify I look inside the folders with the name `Project` to improve the performance of the script 3.The second script I'm trying is not iterating, so it does not work because when I run it, it only finds the first folder and dont searching inside the others folders, Thanks for trying to help me. I hope that now it has given me to understand =D

Comment: Thank you for the detail response. I think that I could understand what you want to do. So I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I try to iterate between folders until I find the folder with the name Project and inside that folder keep iterating until I find the file with the name Test and that it is type spreadsheet.
> 2. The first script if it finds the file but I want to specify I look inside the folders with the name Project to improve the performance of the script
> 3. The second script I'm trying is not iterating, so it does not work because when I run it, it only finds the first folder and dont searching inside the others folders, Thanks for trying to help me. I hope that now it has given me to understand

From your this reply, I could understand as follows.

- You want to retrieve Spreadsheet with the filename of `Test` under the folder with the name of `Project`. You want to do this with low process cost.

If my understanding is correct, how about these sample scripts? Please choose from them for your situation. I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this answer as one of them.

### Pattern 1:

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve files from filename of `Test` using `getFilesByName()`.
2. Retrieve parent folders of each file using `getParents()`.
3. If the folder name is `Project` and the mimeType is Spreadsheet, it retrieves the file.

#### Sample script:

```
var fileName = "Test";
var folderName = "Project";
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var parents = file.getParents();
  while (parents.hasNext()) {
    var parent = parents.next();
    if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS && parent.getName() == folderName) {

      // do something

    }
  }
}
```

### Pattern 2:

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve folders from folder name of `Project` using `getFoldersByName()`.
2. Retrieve files in each folders using `getFilesByName()`.
3. If the filename is `Test` and the mimeType is Spreadsheet, it retrieves the file.

#### Sample script:

```
var fileName = "Test";
var folderName = "Project";
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = folders.next();
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS && file.getName() == fileName) {

      // do something

    }
  }
}
```

### Pattern 3:

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve folder IDs of folder name of `Project` using `getFoldersByName()`.
2. Retrieve files with the parent folder of `Project` and the filename of `Test` and the mimeType of Spreadsheet using `searchFiles()`.

#### Sample script:

```
var fileName = "Test";
var folderName = "Project";
var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
var folderIds = [];
while (folders.hasNext()) {
  folderIds.push(folders.next().getId());
}
folderIds.forEach(function(id) {
  var params = "'" + id + "' in parents and title='" + fileName + "' and mimeType='" + MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS + "'";
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(params);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();

      // do something

  }
});
```

#### References:

- [getFilesByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename)
- [getFoldersByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename)
- [getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents)
- [searchFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams)

If these were not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Let me try it with all the patterns, just two things if you can help me please, when I use `DriveApp.getFilesByName` or `DriveApp.getFoldersByName`, it starts searching all my drive and I need to start searching in a specific folder so it does not search the entire drive And the second, can you explain me the second pattern please?

Comment: @LsAlb ``DriveApp.getFilesByName`` and ``DriveApp.getFoldersByName`` can retrieve the files and folders using the name from all files and folders in own Google Drive. You want to retrieve Spreadsheet with the filename of Test under the folder with the name of Project. I could understand about what you want to do. Is my understanding not correct? I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.